# .htaccess переадресанция с одно страницы с Get параметрами на другую страницу, сохранив параметры

Tags: .htaccess

Добрый день.
Не могу найти в интернете как сделать с помощью .htaccess переадресанция с одно страницы с Get параметрами (или без них) на другую страницу, сохранив параметры?

есть адрес:
http://site.ru/%D0%A0%C2%B7%D0%A0%C2%B0%D0%A0%D1%94%D0%A0%C2%B0%D0%A0%C2%B7%D0%A0%C2%B0%D0%A1%E2%80%9A%D0%A1%D0%8A-%D0%A1%D0%82%D0%A0%C2%B0%D0%A0%C2%B1%D0%A0%D1%95%D0%A1%E2%80%9A%D0%A1%D1%93.html?utm_source=vk&utm_medium=grup&utm_campaign=info&utm_term=general

К сожалению, название страницы было кирилицецей из-за этого много проблем, сейчас сделали просто:
http://site.ru/order.html

как сделать чтобы запросы с прошлой страницы приходили на эту сроаницу, сохранив Get параметры если они есть?
Спасибо.

Comment: В RewriteRule во флагах `QSA` пропишите, пример: [R=301,L,QSA]

Comment: прошу прощения, но я не совсем понял?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)фраза(.*)$ http://avtomat5.ru/order.html [L,R=301]
```

Comment: правильный ответ

Comment: отметьте свой ответ галочкой